# Pandas 'concat/upsert' dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking for an efficient way to select matching rows in 2 x dataframes based on a shared row value, and upsert these into a new dataframe I can use to map differences between the intersection of them into a third slightly different dataframe that compares them.

```
**Example:**

DataFrame1
FirstName, City
Mark, London
Mary, Dallas
Abi, Madrid
Eve, Paris
Robin, New York

DataFrame2
FirstName, City
Mark, Berlin
Abi, Delhi
Eve, Paris
Mary, Dallas
Francis, Rome
```

In the dataframes, I have potential matching/overlapping on 'name', so the intersection on these is:

```
Mark, Mary, Abi, Eve
```

excluded from the join are:

```
Robin, Francis
```

I construct a dataframe that allows values from both to be compared:

```
DataFrameMatch
FirstName_1, FirstName_2, FirstName_Match, City_1, City_2, City_Match
```

And insert/update (upsert) so my output is:

```
DataFrameMatch
FirstName_1  FirstName_2  FirstName_Match  City_1  City_2  City_Match
Mark         Mark         True             London  Berlin  False
Abi          Abi          True             Madrid  Delhi   False
Mary         Mary         True             Dallas  Dallas  True
Eve          Eve          True             Paris   Paris   True
```

I can then report on the difference between the two lists, and what particular fields are different.

Comment: What you describe is not an upsert. An upsert modifies existing data. You're trying to generate a new copy of the data.

Comment: thanks @jpmc26 ... my fault for not communicating it correctly ... I was initially thinking of bringing in one set of data, then the other on top of that, updating based on the key-field if the previous dataset had already brought it in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### `merge`

According to your output.  You only want rows where `'FirstName'` matches.  You then want another column that evaluates whether cities match.

```
d1.merge(d2, on='FirstName', suffixes=['_1', '_2']).eval('City_Match = City_1 == City_2')

  FirstName  City_1  City_2  City_Match
0      Mark  London  Berlin       False
1      Mary  Dallas  Dallas        True
2       Abi  Madrid   Delhi       False
3       Eve   Paris   Paris        True
```

---

#### Details

You could do a simple `merge` and end up with

```
  FirstName    City
0      Mary  Dallas
1       Eve   Paris
```

Which takes all common columns by default.  So I had to restrict the columns via the `on` argument, hence `on='FirstName'`

```
d1.merge(d2, on='FirstName')

  FirstName  City_x  City_y
0      Mark  London  Berlin
1      Mary  Dallas  Dallas
2       Abi  Madrid   Delhi
3       Eve   Paris   Paris
```

Which gets us closer but now I want to adjust those suffixes.

```
d1.merge(d2, on='FirstName', suffixes=['_1', '_2'])

  FirstName  City_1  City_2
0      Mark  London  Berlin
1      Mary  Dallas  Dallas
2       Abi  Madrid   Delhi
3       Eve   Paris   Paris
```

Lastly, I'll add a new column that shows the evaluation of `'city_1'` being equal to `'city_2'`.  I chose to use `pandas.DataFrame.eval`.  You can see the results above.

Comment: Thanks @piRSquared ... I tried this in my cut-down dataset, which is 30mb and it quickly gives a memory error (surprising as I have 128gb on the machine) ...  my actual production datasets to compare are 300 + 350 MBs ... so I assume the next step is to read one of the files in using chunks and just keep merging?